# How to produce a similar plot? [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

The authors of this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867415006418) mention in their supplementary file that these were produced in Matlab. Due to lack of proficiency, time to learn it, and the license, I was trying to replicate the figure below (Figure 2 of the paper, **specifically figure 2A on the left**) in R:
[image]

***Any suggestions? What is this plot called more generally?***

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any data to share to make it easier to help you?

Comment: This is not my data as suggested by the prompt.

Comment: In this case I've not downvoted yet. However given fake data similar to yours it's going to be easier to provide working code for your problem. To help you, we I have to invent some data, hoping that are *maybe* are similar to your, and create some code that is based some data that are possibly wrong.

Comment: In case, if the question is only "how is it called this plot?", this question does not fit with the SO standard, because it is not code related, and it could be closed. Data are helpful to help you to create the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a classic point plot! You can reproduce this kind of plot in R with ggplot:

```
# Fake dataframe with xy coordinates, type of data (for the coloring), pvalue (for size), and different panel
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:20, 10),
  y = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 2),
  type = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 4), 10),
  pvalue = sample(0:50, size = 200, replace = T)/1000,
  panel = sample(rep(paste0("panel", 1:4), each = 50)), 200, replace = F)


# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y*x , color = type, size = pvalue)) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~panel, ncol = 2)

ggsave("demo.png")
```

[image]